# Sales Order Barcode table in magento

Tags: sql, database, magento, magento-1.8

I need to know table name of save sales order Barcode in magento database, for create custom report in asp.net. i have successfully connected to mysql and sample database and successfully fetch data from sample table and show in report, but i can't find sales order barcode in magento tables. if you know table name of save sales order barcode please answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find order items SKU from the table "sales_flat_order_item"